# How can I move items from one chest to another using commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a mailbox system and want to have the items in a chest teleported to another chest where I can pickup my 'mail'.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What do you want to accomplish? (flagged)

Comment: @ardaozkal, what is unclear to you? OP wishes to teleport items from one chest to another. They wish to do so for a mailing system.

Comment: @Timelord64 oh, the title says that. Sorry, I just read the content.

Answer (score 3):

The [`/clone`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#clone) command can copy the chest and place it elsewhere:

```
/clone <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> <x> <y> <z> [maskMode] [cloneMode] [TileName]
```

For example, if the chest you're inserting items to is at X0, Y64, Z0, and the mailbox chest is at X100, Y64, Z100:

```
/clone 0 64 0 0 64 0 100 64 100
```

---

Keep in mind that this requires both coordinate locations to be loaded. You can use the [`/spreadplayers`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#spreadplayers) command to forcibly load the chunks using a dummy entity such as an armor stand just before running the /clone command.

```
/spreadplayers <x> <z> <spreadDistance> <maxRange> <respectTeams> <player …>

/spreadplayers 0 0 0 1 false @e[type=ArmorStand,name=anchor]
/spreadplayers 100 100 0 1 false @e[type=ArmorStand,name=anchor]
/clone 0 64 0 0 64 0 100 64 100
```

---

And one other thing to note is that the contents of the mailbox will be completely replaced, so any items that were still in that chest will be deleted. A solution to that is to clone the initial chest above a hopper above the mailbox chest, such that the items will be transferred to the mailbox.

You could also use `/setblock` to destroy the cloned chest such that the items will be dropped instantly and do not have the risk of being deleted as well.

```
/setblock 100 64 100 minecraft:air 0 destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with commands, but there are several methods to transport items. Firstly, you can use minecarts and rails, secondly, you can use hoppers or droppers.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do this with commands (yet) as chest data is store in NBT tags and there are no commands in the code that handle item transfer like that.

Ender Chests are an option if using a command isn't essential.